# Why music downloader apps return unrelated, foreign-language songs?

Tags: music, downloading

Every time I search for music in *redacted* apps, all do the same thing. Any artist or song I try to find, the search results find a few but are not that song or artist. They show up in some weird language.

Why is that?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the weird language? I'm guessing the language isn't one used in your country?

Comment: I have a screenshot but not sure how to post it on here...

Comment: edit your answer, and click the image icon in the editor.

Comment: Because they usually run it on different databases such as vimeo, vk, Youtube etc. and some person who uploads a video titled **ღჯუკეჱნგშწზ** tag-spams it with tags that include the word you search too. And therefore, your search also returns it.

Answer (score 1):

Such app would be illegal: to keep working they usually do a really simple thing, using a [dork](http://www.exploit-db.com/google-dorks/) they search on google for your song and show an ordered list of results.

Since google is becoming more and more intelligent it will not index copyrighted songs. Just deal with it.

Another way to download song from your phone, is to use a youtube-2-mp3 app/site. Much faster and easier.